# cakephp 2x + ajax pagination + prototype js

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

i want to create add/edit/delete and active/deactive (with ajax) in the listing page.
here i have uploaded the demo http://mehul.pw/cp/categories/index
right now pagination is working fine. but when i change the status and then use the pagination then its not working. i am trying to solve this from 3hr
here i have mentioned below my code

controller code is below:

```
    public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Prototype'));
    public $components = array();

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 1,
        'order' => array(
            'Category.category_id' => 'asc'
        )
    );
    public function index()
    {

        $data = $this->paginate('Category');
    $this->set('categories',$data);

    }
 public function update($field,$value,$id = null,$pageno,$sortkey,$sortdir)
    {

        if (!$id) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for Event', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Category->id = $id;
        $this->request->data['Category'][$field] = $value;
        if($this->Category->save($this->request->data))
    {
           $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index', 'page' => $pageno, 'sort' => $sortkey, 'direction' => $sortdir));
        }else{
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index', 'page' => $pageno, 'sort' => $sortkey, 'direction' => $sortdir));
    }
    }
}
```

Now in my index file
for active/deactive link i have used this

```
<?php
            if($post['Category']['is_active'] == 'Y'){
                echo $this->Js->link( 'Active', array('action' => 'update','is_active','N', $post['Category']['category_id'],$this->paginator->current(),$this->paginator->sortKey(),$this->paginator->sortDir()), array('async' => false,'update' => 'content'));    
            }else{
                echo $this->Js->link( 'DeActive', array('action' => 'update','is_active','Y', $post['Category']['category_id'],$this->paginator->current(),$this->paginator->sortKey(),$this->paginator->sortDir()), array('async' => false,'update' => 'content'));    
            }

            ?>
```

can you tell me how can i solve this issue ?
Thanks in advance.

here i have also tried to use the ajax helper but the dame issue
here belo i mentioned a fill view code

```
<?php // pr($this->Paginator->options);
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'update' => '#content',
    'evalScripts' => true,
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
    'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
));
?>

<h1>Categories List</h1>
<?php //echo $this->Html->link('Add Post',array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'add')); ?>
<?php echo $this->html->link('Add Category',array('controller'=>'categories','action'=>'add'),array("escape" => false,'class'=>'stdbtn btn_orange', "title" => "Add Category", "onclick" => "Modalbox.show(this.href, {title: this.title, width: 700}); return false;")); ?>

<table>
    <?php

    //echo $this->Html->tableHeaders(array('Date','Title','Active'),array('class' => 'status'),array('class' => 'product_table'));?>
    <tr>

        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('category_id', '<em>Category Id</em>', array('escape' => false)); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('category_name', '<em>Name</em>', array('escape' => false)); ?></th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Action</th>        
    </tr>
    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php  foreach ($categories as $post): ?>
    <tr>
         <td><?php echo $post['Category']['category_id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Category']['category_name'],array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $post['Category']['category_id'])); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $post['Category']['description']; ?></td>
        <td>

            <?php
            if($post['Category']['is_active'] == 'Y'){
                echo $this->Js->link( 'Active', array('action' => 'update','is_active','N', $post['Category']['category_id'],$this->paginator->current(),$this->paginator->sortKey(),$this->paginator->sortDir()), array('async' => false,'update' => 'content'));    
            }else{
                echo $this->Js->link( 'DeActive', array('action' => 'update','is_active','Y', $post['Category']['category_id'],$this->paginator->current(),$this->paginator->sortKey(),$this->paginator->sortDir()), array('async' => false,'update' => 'content'));    
            }

            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
                'Delete',
                array('action' => 'delete', $post['Category']['category_id']),
                array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?'));
            ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $post['Category']['category_id'])); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="right">
         <?php

        echo $this->Paginator->first('< first  ');
        echo $this->Paginator->prev(' << ' . __('previous  '), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers();    
        echo $this->Paginator->next( __('  next').' >> ' , array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));  
        echo $this->Paginator->last('  Last > ');  


        //echo $this->Paginator->counter('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of{:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}');
        ?>

        <?php echo $this->Html->image('indicator.gif', array('id' => 'busy-indicator')); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php unset($post);

    ?>
</table>

<?php  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

===================== My Layout code ==============

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * PHP 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.View.Layouts
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.10.0.1076
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

$cakeDescription = __d('cake_dev', 'CakePHP: the rapid development php framework');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
    <title>
        <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>:
        <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
    </title>
    <?php
        echo $this->Html->meta('icon');

        echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');

        echo $this->fetch('meta');
        echo $this->fetch('css');
        echo $this->fetch('script');
    ?>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('modalbox.js');   echo $this->Html->css('modalbox.css'); ?>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1><?php echo $this->Html->link($cakeDescription, 'http://cakephp.org'); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">

            <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>

            <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
            <?php  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(
                    $this->Html->image('cake.power.gif', array('alt' => $cakeDescription, 'border' => '0')),
                    'http://www.cakephp.org/',
                    array('target' => '_blank', 'escape' => false)
                );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>` before closing the `<div id='content'>`

I think your pagination links aren't updating here once if you fire an ajax call the content is updating but the pagination links and the related script for the pagination links aren't updating here,

i.e.

```
$("link-907864750").observe("click", function (event) {event.stop();
var jsRequest = new Ajax.Updater("content", "/cp/categories/index/sort:category_name/direction:asc", {evalScripts:true, onComplete:function (transport) {$("busy-indicator").fade({buffer:false});}, onCreate:function (transport) {$("busy-indicator").appear({buffer:false});}});});
```

`$("link-907864750")` is the link you are having at first time later when you click on 'deactive' or 'active' this isn't updating the script/ not even generating the script for pagination links there.

**Note:** `$("#link-907864750")` is an example here, cake will generate random ids for the pagination links.

Comment: I can help you, if you provide me the view code of your application, since I've faced same issue in my app.

Comment: is this `<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>` inside the element which you want i.e here the element with id `#content`, just asking

Comment: here in question i have added my layout code too. so you can check it

Comment: After deactivating/activating you're not updating the script for the pagination links

Comment: can you tell me how to append it ?

Comment: Don't redirect in update function, instead write like this `$this->render('index')`, it will work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36798/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-deck-john)